# How to get the address of a reference variable?

Tags: c#

Basically here i would like to to show the strings are immutable with an example so i took the below  example and I know that GetHashCode() doesn't return address but how can i differentiate both variables refer to the different memory location?

In the below code i want the address of a string variable

```
        string s = "hello";
        Console.WriteLine(s.GetHashCode());
        s = s + "User";
        Console.WriteLine(s.GetHashCode());
```

But in String Builder case GetHashCode() returns same value

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("hi");
        Console.WriteLine(sb.GetHashCode());
        sb.Append("hello");
        Console.WriteLine(sb.GetHashCode());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use two different variables and [`object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) instead:

```
string x = "hello";
string y = x + "User";
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(x, y));
```

Admittedly just printing `x` and `y` at that point would show that they're different... as a slight alternative:

```
string s = "hello";
string original = s;
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(s, original)); // True
s = s + "User";
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(s, original)); // False
```

Perhaps that's closer to what you were looking for?

Comment: @Skeet shouldn't that be `Object.ReferenceEquals(...)` in each case?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance please elaborate.

Comment: @feralin: It's calling `object.ReferenceEquals` anyway - you can qualify it if you want, but you don't have to.

Comment: @feralin All objects inherit from object, therefore it inherits their methods

Comment: @Skeet ah, I see. I forgot that `ReferenceEquals` would be in scope basically anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 7):

For your given example, you don't actually need to know the address--you only want to know whether the address of two objects is the same.

```
string s1 = "hi";
string s2 = s1;
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2)); // True
s2 = s2 + " world";
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2)); // False
```

**Fun Side Note**: `object`'s `==` operator defaults to using `object.ReferenceEquals()`, but because `string` in C# overrides the `==` operator, checking equality between two strings will be based on whether the strings are equal. To further complicate things, the compiler "interns" any constant strings that it can tell are exactly equal at compile time. The combination of these behaviors leaves you with some really odd behavior:

```
string s1 = "john";
object s2 = "john";
string s3 = new StringBuilder(s1).ToString();
Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2); // True
Console.WriteLine(s2 == s1); // True
Console.WriteLine(s1 == s3); // True
Console.WriteLine(s3 == s1); // True
Console.WriteLine(s2 == s3); // False
Console.WriteLine(s3 == s2); // False
```

Comment: @feralin: You're in good company. I somehow managed to beat Skeet to it, too!

Answer (score 0):

`Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)` returns `false` iff `a` and `b` are references to different objects (and thus different addresses).

The hash code for the string builder is presumably constructed from the string builder's address, not from the string value it stores.

`s + "hello"`, on the other hand, creates a new object which has a different hash code than `s`.